Longtable not splitting row across pages in LyX 2.3.7
I have documentation in which the contents of a table's cell might be longer than a page's length. Hence to enable splitting a cell across multiple pages, I have utilized longtable in the latex preamble and the same is also reflecting in the code preview pane.

However, despite it showing as a longtable, the cell is not being split across pages, and is overflowing on a single page with the content being lost.
I am utilizing a multipage table, with a few of the rows being set as multi-column. Also, there is no option for checkbox for longtable in the table settings as is mentioned in some of the answers here. The "Page break on current row" option also doesn't change this.

I am using LyX version 2.3.7 right now.
How do I actually split the cell across pages?
Edit:
Adding a sample screenshot of test content I am trying to put inside the table, the table settings and the output.







Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...


I have utilized longtable in the latex preamble

Do not do that. The package is added automatically with a right-clik mouse on the table, then ☐ Multi-page Table → ☑ Multi-page Table.

However, ... the cell is not being split across pages

This is the guessing  part: You put the longtable inside a table float or another unbreakable box. This is wrong.
The longtable of the next screenshot split well. Note that the caption is not made including a float as the first short and floating  table, but setting Caption: ☑  On  in the menu that you show in the question.

Edit: OK, a new screenshot has proven once again that it is not wise to play guessing games:
Any kind of table cannot be split in the middle of the row. It can be split only between rows. Of course this is also true for tables of a single column. Cells of a tabular like-environment cannot be slitted in any way (except manually). You cannot make endless cells that cannot be fitted in the height of the available space in the page. Is up tu you make a empty rows below and move the excess of text to the next rows.
Said that, you can make breakable boxes  with the tcolorbox package, that can be used to mimic a table with a single column of breakable cells like here. As stated in the comments, now LyX also support this package at some extent via Document→Settings...ModulesFancy Coloured Boxes→Add→OK  and then use Insert→Custom insets but probably for some complex boxes  could be simpler add the package manually in the LaTeX preamble with the right options and settings and  adding raw LaTeX ERT boxes in text (Ctrl+L).

Hi Fran, the longtable is not inside a float environment. Can you please suggest what else I can check to rectify this?

Fran gave a nice answer. @Aryan you gave nice details in your question but you're missing a minimal example .lyx file. You can actually copy/paste the .lyx contents into the question as code. Please read: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

@Aryan Cells are not breakable at all! The table can be splitted  between  rows, not within roos, for any kind of tabular-like environment. It is you to you split the cells (rows) or change completely of approach. For a table of a single column you can use tcolorbox, for instance, that is not managed by Lyx (will need ERT boxes to include raw LaTeX). See see here or here for examples.

There is a module called Fancy Colored Boxes to support tcolorbox that is shipped with LyX

@UdiFogiel True. I use LyX sporadically and I had not realized that they had included this module. Thanks for point out.
